# Trying to use CoCalc (sage) to plot solutions to a function requiring a modulus

Tags: python, sage

I have the following code and error message.  Something I am doing seems to be messing up the % function in the hb function.   I'm not really sure what or how to fix it.  Any ideas?

```
def h(n):
    if (n % 4 >= 0) and (n % 4 < 1):
            k = 1
    else:
        k = 0
    return k

def hb(n):
    if (((n/4) % 2) >= 0) and (((n/4) % 2) < 1):
        k = -1*h(n)
    else:
        k = h(n)
    return k

def dalembert(y,t):
    x = 0.5*hb(y-t)+0.5*hb(y+t) 
    return x 

import numpy as np

box1 = np.array([1,2,6,10,20])

for i in range(len(box1)):
    g=Graphics()
    g += plot(dalembert(x,box1[i]), (x, 0, 4), color='blue')
    g.show()
```

Error in lines 18-21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cocalc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 1188, in execute
    flags=compile_flags) in namespace, locals
  File "", line 3, in 
  File "", line 2, in dalembert
  File "", line 2, in hb
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 1925, in sage.structure.element.Element.**mod** (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:13956)
    return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, mod)
  File "sage/structure/coerce.pyx", line 1182, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:9827)
    return PyObject_CallObject(op, xy)
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 1923, in sage.structure.element.Element.**mod** (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:13921)
    return (left).*mod*(right)
  File "sage/structure/element.pyx", line 1958, in sage.structure.element.Element.*mod* (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:14242)
    raise bin_op_exception('%', self, other)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for %: 'Symbolic Ring' and 'Symbolic Ring'

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 

`g += plot(dalembert(x,box1[i]), (x, 0, 4), color='blue')`

with  *something like*

`function d0(y):
    return dalembert(y,box1[i]);
g += plot(d0, (x, 0, 4), color='blue')`

The problem is that when you write `dalembert(x,box1[i])` in your code, it is evaluated first before even getting to using that in a plot, and it's evaluated with x a symbolic, which breaks other things...